# Converting Access OLE object image to show in Datagridview vb.net

Tags: vb.net, ms-access, oledb

I'm trying to load data from an Access database into a DataGridView.

This is my access database - Image has long binary data

[image]

However, when I retrieve the data from the database and try to load it into the DataGridView, it shows this error:

[image: DataGridView error]

I have 2 forms, this one is for adding to database:

[image: Add to database]

This one is for showing the database in the DataGridView

[image: Display Data]

Here's my code to add my uploaded image to database.

```
Dim fsreader As New FileStream(OpenFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim breader As New BinaryReader(fsreader)
    Dim imgbuffer(fsreader.Length) As Byte
    breader.Read(imgbuffer, 0, fsreader.Length)
    fsreader.Close()


    Dim create As New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Officials ([officialname] , [age] , [birthdate] , [position] , [term], [status], [image] ) VALUES ('" & TextBox1.Text & "' ,  '" & TextBox2.Text & "' , '" & DateTimePicker1.Value & "' , '" & cb1 & "' , '" & TextBox3.Text & "' , '" & status & "' , @img )", con)
    With create
        .Parameters.Add("@on", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox1.Text.Trim
        .Parameters.Add("@age", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox2.Text.Trim
        .Parameters.Add("@bd", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = DateTimePicker1.Value
        .Parameters.Add("@pn", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = cb1
        .Parameters.Add("@tm", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = TextBox3.Text.Trim
        .Parameters.Add("@st", OleDb.OleDbType.VarChar).Value = status
        .Parameters.Add("@img", OleDb.OleDbType.LongVarBinary).Value = imgbuffer
```

Answer (score 0):

I can give you an example how to put images on a DataGridView from Access but you'll need to adapt to your reality.

Just add a DataGridView and create 2 columns, first as TextBoxColumn and second as ImageColumn.

The next step is to load data from access database, so use what you already have that is not shown in your post. It will be something like:

```
Dim GConn As New OleDbConnection("your connection string...")
Dim GCmd As New OleDbCommand()
Dim DtReader As OleDbDataReader

GCmd.Connection = GConn 
GCmd.CommandText = "SELECT PhotoDescription, PhotoOLE FROM MY_TABLE;"

DtReader = GCmd.ExecuteReader ' DtReader will have all the rows from database

' For this test you need to load less than 100 records
dim iLine as integer=0    
DataGridView1.rows.Add(100) ' add 100 rows to test

DtReader.Read ' read first record

Do
    DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells(0).Value=DtReader("PhotoDescription").ToString
    DataGridView1.Rows(iLine).Cells(1).Value=CType(DtReader("PhotoOLE"), Byte())
    iLine+=1  
Loop while DtReader.Read
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not necessary to store both `birthdate` and `age`, because one of them can be computed given a value for the other one.

You haven't provided enough code to identify the issue, but if the image data wasn't properly converted before storing it, that would cause an issue.

Below shows how to both insert and update data that contains an image, as well as how to retrieve the data. In the code below, you'll also find code that will create an Access database and a table.

Add a reference to `Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security`

**Note**: This is required for the "CreateDatabase" function in the code below.

- In VS menu, click **Project**
- Select **Add Reference...**
- Select **COM**
- Check **Microsoft ADO Ext. 6.0 for DDL and Security**

The code is tested and fairly well-documented. Of particular importance are the following functions/methods:

- GetImageAsByteArray
- TblOfficialsExecuteNonQuery
- TblOfficialsInsert
- TblOfficialsGetData

Create a class (name: HelperAccess.vb)

```
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.IO

Public Class HelperAccess
    Private _accessFilename As String = String.Empty
    Private _connectionStr As String = String.Empty

    Public ReadOnly Property AccessFilename
        Get
            Return _accessFilename
        End Get
    End Property

    Sub New(accessFilename As String, Optional dbPassword As String = "")
        'set value
        _accessFilename = accessFilename

        'create connection string
        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPassword) Then
            _connectionStr = String.Format("Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source = {0};Jet OLEDB:Database Password='{1}'", accessFilename, dbPassword)
        Else
            _connectionStr = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};", _accessFilename)
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Function CreateDatabase() As String
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        Dim cat As ADOX.Catalog = Nothing

        Try
            'create New instance
            cat = New ADOX.Catalog()

            'create Access database
            cat.Create(_connectionStr)

            'set value
            result = String.Format("Status: Database created: '{0}'", _accessFilename)

            Return result
        Catch ex As Exception
            'set value
            result = String.Format("Error (CreateDatabase): {0}(Database: {1})", ex.Message, _accessFilename)
            Return result

        Finally
            If cat IsNot Nothing Then
                'close connection
                cat.ActiveConnection.Close()

                'release COM object
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(cat)

                cat = Nothing
            End If
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Function CreateTblOfficials() As String
        Dim result As String = String.Empty

        Dim tableName As String = "Officials"

        Dim sqlText = String.Empty
        sqlText = "CREATE TABLE Officials "
        sqlText += "(ID AUTOINCREMENT not null primary key,"
        sqlText += " [FullName] varchar(50) not null,"
        sqlText += " [Birthdate] DateTime,"
        sqlText += " [JobDescription] varchar(50) not null,"
        sqlText += " [Term] varchar(50),"
        sqlText += " [Status] varchar(50) not null,"
        sqlText += " [Photo] Longbinary);"

        Try
            'create database table
            ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText)

            result = String.Format("Table created: '{0}'", tableName)

        Catch ex As OleDbException
            result = String.Format("Error (CreateTblOfficials - OleDbException): Table creation failed: '{0}'; {1}", tableName, ex.Message)
        Catch ex As Exception
            result = String.Format("Error (CreateTblOfficials): Table creation failed: '{0}'; {1}", tableName, ex.Message)
        End Try

        Return result
    End Function

    Private Function ExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        'used for insert/update

        'create new connection
        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            'create new instance
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn)
                'execute
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Public Function GetImageAsByteArray(filename As String) As Byte()
        'read image from file and return as Byte()

        Try
            If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename) AndAlso System.IO.File.Exists(filename) Then
                Using fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
                    Dim imageBytes(fs.Length) As Byte

                    'read image from file and put into Byte()
                    fs.Read(imageBytes, 0, fs.Length)

                    Return imageBytes
                End Using
            End If
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (GetImageAsByteArray): " + ex.Message)
            Throw
        End Try

        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Function TblOfficialsExecuteNonQuery(sqlText As String, fullName As String, birthdate As Date, jobDescription As String, term As String, status As String, imageBytes As Byte()) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        'create new connection
        Using cn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
            'open
            cn.Open()

            'create new instance
            Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, cn)

                'OLEDB doesn't use named parameters in SQL. Any names specified in a SQL query will be discarded.
                'using '?' in the SQL query, as specified in the MS documentation, serves as a reminder
                'that named parameters aren't supported. However, specifying names in the parameter 'Add' statement 
                'can be useful for debugging. Since OLEDB uses positional parameters, the order which the parameters 
                'are added is important. If a column is referenced more than once in the SQL, 
                'then it must be added as a parameter more than once
                'parameters must be added in the order that they are specified in the SQL
                'if a value is null, the value must be assigned as: DBNull.Value

                With cmd.Parameters
                    .Add("!fullName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(fullName), DBNull.Value, fullName)
                    .Add("!birthDate", OleDbType.Date).Value = birthdate
                    .Add("!jobDescription", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(jobDescription), DBNull.Value, jobDescription)
                    .Add("!term", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(term), DBNull.Value, term)
                    .Add("!status", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(status), DBNull.Value, status)

                    'set size to -1, otherwise it defaults to a maxium of 8000
                    .Add("!photo", OleDbType.VarBinary, -1).Value = imageBytes
                End With

                'ToDo: remove the following code that is for debugging
                'For Each p As OleDbParameter In cmd.Parameters
                'Debug.WriteLine(p.ParameterName & ": " & p.Value.ToString())
                'Next

                'execute
                rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            End Using
        End Using

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function

    Public Function TblOfficialsGetData() As DataTable
        Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable()

        Dim sqlText As String = "SELECT * from Officials"

        Try
            'create new connection
            Using con As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection(_connectionStr)
                'open
                con.Open()

                'create new instance
                Using cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(sqlText, con)
                    Using da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(cmd)
                        'fill DataTable from database
                        da.Fill(dt)
                    End Using
                End Using
            End Using

            Return dt
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsGetData - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsGetData) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try

    End Function

    Public Function TblOfficialsInsert(fullName As String, birthdate As Date, jobDescription As String, term As String, status As String, imageBytes As Byte()) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        Dim sqlText As String = String.Empty
        sqlText = "INSERT INTO Officials ([FullName], [BirthDate], [JobDescription], [Term], [Status], [Photo]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?);"

        Try
            'insert data to database
            Return TblOfficialsExecuteNonQuery(sqlText, fullName, birthdate, jobDescription, term, status, imageBytes)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsInsert - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsInsert) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex

        End Try

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function


    Public Function TblOfficialsUpdate(fullName As String, birthdate As Date, jobDescription As String, term As String, status As String, imageBytes As Byte()) As Integer
        Dim rowsAffected As Integer = 0

        Dim sqlText As String = String.Empty
        sqlText = "UPDATE Officials SET [FullName] = ?, [Birthdate] = ? , [JobDescription] = ?, [Term] = ?, [Status] = ?, [Photo] = ?;"

        Try
            'update data in database
            Return TblOfficialsExecuteNonQuery(sqlText, fullName, birthdate, jobDescription, term, status, imageBytes)
        Catch ex As OleDbException
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsUpdate - OleDbException) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        Catch ex As Exception
            Debug.WriteLine("Error (TblOfficialsUpdate) - " & ex.Message & "(" & sqlText & ")")
            Throw ex
        End Try

        Return rowsAffected
    End Function
End Class
```

---

**Usage**

**Create Access Database**:

```
Private _helper As HelperAccess = Nothing
            ...
Dim sfd As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog()

sfd.Filter = "Access Database (*.accdb)|*.accdb|Access Database (*.mdb)|*.mdb"

If sfd.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
    'create new instance
    _helper = New HelperAccess(sfd.FileName)

    Dim result As String = _helper.CreateDatabase()
End If
```

**Create Table**

```
Private _helper As HelperAccess = Nothing
               ...
Dim result As String = _helper.CreateTblOfficials()
```

[image]

**Insert data to database**:

```
Private _helper As HelperAccess = Nothing
               ...
Dim imageBytes As Byte() = Nothing
imageBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\Temp\Images\Test1.jpg")
_helper.TblOfficialsInsert("Joe Smith", New Date(1986, 5, 20), "Captain", "2016-2030", "Active", imageBytes)
```

[image]

**Get data from database**:

Add a `DataGridView` to your form from the Toolbox (don't add any columns)

```
Private _dt As DataTable = New DataTable()
Private _helper As HelperAccess = Nothing
Private _source As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
               ...

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    'set properties
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = False
    DataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = False

    'set data source
    DataGridView1.DataSource = _source
End Sub

Private Sub GetData()
     'get data from database
     _dt = _helper.TblOfficialsGetData()

     'set value
     _source.DataSource = _dt
     _source.ResetBindings(True)
 End Sub
```

**Resources**

- [CREATE TABLE statement (Microsoft Access SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/access/desktop-database-reference/create-table-statement-microsoft-access-sql)
- [How can I refresh c# dataGridView after update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7008361/how-can-i-refresh-c-sharp-datagridview-after-update)
- [Getting binary data using SqlDataReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5371222/getting-binary-data-using-sqldatareader)