# C# Cannot modify an Access DataBase

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, datagridview, oledb

I'm trying to modify an specific register on Access by C# but when I run the code, It doesn't modify anything, I have tried the same structure on adding resgisters or deleting and it works well, Help please

using OleDB

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                
                string sql = "UPDATE Medicos SET Id_clinica=@Id_clinica, Id_especialidad=@Id_especialidad, Nombre=@Nombre, Apellidos=@Apellidos WHERE Id_medico=@Id_medico";
                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(cs);
                con.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, con);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_medico", textBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_clinica", textBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id_especialidad", textBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombre", textBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellidos", textBox5.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
```

Comment: OleDb parameters are positional. You should add them to the parameters collection in the same order in which they appear in the query text. Move the parameter for the WHERE condition in the last position

Comment: Also do not use AddWithValue. This method treats the parameter's type as the input value. I doubt that all those ids are strings. Things go very bad with dates and decimals. Instead use the Add method specifying the parameter type

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425

Comment: Thanks!! It was the position on my parameters