# OleDBException Reading Excel File - Reader not being closed, but where?

Tags: vb.net

I apologize in advance if this has been answered before. I searched for it but could not find anything explaining this particular issue.

I'm getting the OleDb exception 0x80004005 - Cannot open any more tables while reading a large Excel spreadsheet. It parses around 2000 records correctly than breaks.

I searched for this error, which is related to a limit of 2048 tables being open at a given time. I cannot see where my code is wrong, and I think it is, but I need a fresh pair of eyes looking at me to point me out what I'm missing.

This is the code - As you can see, I am closing the reader *ReaderExcelProgramsColumn*

What am I not seeing?

```
 If strSpreadSheetFullPathLowCase.Contains(".xlsx") Then
                strConnectionStringExtendedParameters = ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Mode=Read;Readonly=True"";"
            ElseIf strSpreadSheetFullPathLowCase.Contains(".xlsm") Then
                strConnectionStringExtendedParameters = ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES;IMEX=1;Mode=Read;Readonly=True"";"
            End If

            Dim intColumStartLocator As Integer = 0

            Dim strConnectionStringExcel = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & txtFilePathOpenExcel.Text & strConnectionStringExtendedParameters
            Dim strProgramID As String = Nothing
            Dim strMachinePrefix As String = Nothing
            Dim strProgramFileExtensionFromExcel As String = Nothing
            Dim strLastFileName As String = Nothing
            Dim strLastProgramID As String = Nothing
            Dim strFullFilePath As String = Nothing

            Dim sqlExcelConnection As OleDbConnection = Nothing

            Try
                '/////////////////////////////////////////////
                '// Open the connection with the Excel File //
                '/////////////////////////////////////////////

                lblStatus.Text = "Opening connection with MS-Excel..."
                Application.DoEvents()
                sqlExcelConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionStringExcel)
                sqlExcelConnection.Open()
            Catch ex As Exception
                If (sqlExcelConnection.State = ConnectionState.Open) Then
                    sqlExcelConnection.Dispose()
                End If
                ErrorToReadFromMSExcel(ex.ToString, System.Reflection.MethodInfo.GetCurrentMethod.ToString, True)
                Exit Sub
            End Try

            Try
                Dim strProgramsQuery As String = "SELECT" & vbNewLine &
                                         "[" & cboxExcelCIMCODBFieldProgram.Text & "]" & vbNewLine &
                                         "FROM [" & cboxExcelTabName.Text & "$]"

                Dim Query As String = String.Empty
                Dim sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms As New OleDbCommand(strProgramsQuery, sqlExcelConnection)
                Dim ReaderExcelProgramsColumn As OleDbDataReader = sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.ExecuteReader

                Do While ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Read()
                    If ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.HasRows Then
                        strProgramID = Trim(UCase(ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.GetValue(0).ToString))
     
                        Dim strQuery As String = "SELECT" & vbNewLine &
    "hdrfullprefix" & vbNewLine &
    "FROM " & strCustomNameForHeaderSettingsTable & " AS slb" & vbNewLine &
    "INNER JOIN " & strTableMchGroups & " AS mg" & vbNewLine &
    "WHERE mg." & strMchGroupID & " = slb.machidncbase" & vbNewLine &
    "AND mg." & strMchGroup & " = '" & cboxCIMCOMachineToMigrate.Text & "'" & vbNewLine &
    "ORDER BY id DESC" & vbNewLine &
    "LIMIT 1"

                        strMachinePrefix = RunBasicQueryReturnIsStringOnNCBase(strNCBaseConnectionString, strQuery)

                        If strProgramID <> String.Empty Then
                            lblStatus.Text = "Extracting program '" & strProgramID & "' from the spreadsheet..."
                            Application.DoEvents()
                            arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Add(strProgramID)
                            arrProgramsPrefixes.Add(strMachinePrefix)
                        End If

                        If arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Count = 0 Then
                            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Could not find programs in the spreadsheet in the column '" & cboxExcelCIMCODBFieldProgram.Text & "', tab '" & cboxExcelTabName.SelectedItem.ToString & "' of the selected spreadsheet!" _
                                        & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please check if the column name selected for program extraction is correct in the spreadsheet and try again.", "Could not find programs in the selected spreadsheet!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Else
                        ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()
                        MessageBox.Show(Me, "Could not find programs in the spreadsheet in the column '" & cboxExcelCIMCODBFieldProgram.Text & "', tab '" & cboxExcelTabName.SelectedItem.ToString & "' of the selected spreadsheet!" _
                           & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please check if the column name selected for program extraction is correct in the spreadsheet and try again.", "Could not find programs in the selected spreadsheet!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                        Exit Sub
                    End If
                    strLastProgramID = strProgramID
                    Application.DoEvents()
               Loop
                ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()
                sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.Dispose()
                
                'Close connection to release memory
                ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()
                sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.Dispose()
                sqlExcelConnection.Dispose()

                'Open a new connection
                sqlExcelConnection = New OleDbConnection(strConnectionStringExcel)
                sqlExcelConnection.Open()
                
                lblStatus.Text = "Starting data extraction... Please wait..."
                Application.DoEvents()

                '*** Sort the array ***
                arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Sort()

                '*** Capture Program Extensions ***

                For i As Integer = 0 To arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Count - 1

                    strProgramsQuery = "SELECT TOP 1 [" & strProgramFileExtensionNoPunctuation & "] FROM [" & cboxExcelTabName.Text & "$] WHERE [" & cboxExcelCIMCODBFieldProgram.Text & "] = '" & arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Item(i) & "'"
                    sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms = New OleDbCommand(strProgramsQuery, sqlExcelConnection)
                    ReaderExcelProgramsColumn = sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.ExecuteReader

                    Do While ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Read()
                    
                    '*****************************************************************************
                    '** The exception 0x80004005 - Cannot open any more tables occurs somewhere **
                    '** here, even after I closed the connection between the loops.             **
                    '*****************************************************************************
                    
                    
                        If ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.HasRows Then
                            strLastProgramID = arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Item(i)
                            lblStatus.Text = "Extracting the extension of the program '" & arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Item(i) & "' from the spreadsheet..."
                            Application.DoEvents()

                   
                   
                   
                            strProgramFileExtensionFromExcel = Trim(UCase(ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.GetValue(0).ToString))
                            tupleProgramsAndExtensions.Add((arrProgramsInTheSpreadSheet.Item(i), strProgramFileExtensionFromExcel))
                        Else
                            ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()
                            MessageBox.Show(Me, "HeaderPuncher could not find programs in the spreadsheet in the column '" & cboxExcelCIMCODBFieldProgram.Text & "', tab '" & cboxExcelTabName.SelectedItem.ToString & "' of the selected spreadsheet!" _
                               & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & "Please check if the column name selected for program extraction is correct in the spreadsheet and try again.", "Could not find programs in the selected spreadsheet!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation)
                            Exit Sub
                        End If
                    Loop

                Next

                ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()
                sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.Dispose()
                sqlExcelConnection.Dispose()
```

Thanks!

Comment: First, get rid of all of the `Application.DoEvents()` statements. Next, see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425) for how to use parameterized queries, as well as, [Using Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/using-statement). This will help to avoid situations such as calling `ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Close()` and `sqlSelectColumnsExcelPrograms.Dispose()` twice and forgetting to call `ReaderExcelProgramsColumn.Dispose()`.

Comment: For this specific issue, the most important point in the comment above is the `Using` statements. If you ALWAYS create your disposable objects - including database connections, commands and readers - then you can't possibly forget to close them. They will be disposed and thus closed at the end of the block.

Comment: Always _ALWAYS_ **ALWAYS** wrap your connections in a `Using` block.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is what some people mentioned in the comments: The usage of Using / End Using instead of the archaic approach I was using.

Many thanks, everyone!