# I'm getting an error in Visual Studio when I try to connect the program to a database

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

[image]

Please Help
I am a beginner in the visual world
When I try to connect to a database this error appears
Is there any solution please?

Comment: Please explain EXACTLY what you did, step by step, to generate that error. I suspect that VS is corrupt and you will need to repair your installation but it's important that we understand exactly what stage of the process this happened at and whether you did anything weird to cause it so we can eliminate other possibilities. We should be able to follow your instructions for ourselves and see whether the same behaviour is exhibited. If it's not, that suggests corruption on your system. In that case, you should run the VS installer and choose the *Repair* option.

Comment: I'm working on a small project
This is a secondary window in it
In my attempt to link the form to an Access 2019 database
It gives me this message
Although if I open another project and want to insert a database it inserts normally
There is no problem with it except with this project
Exactly, I don't know what I did wrong that might have caused this annoying thing to happen
As I told you, I am a beginner in Visual

Comment: That doesn't address my comment at all. Please read what I wrote and do what I asked. If you don't know what the steps were, go through them again and take notice this time. That said, if you're able to do exactly the same thing in another project then it may just be this project that is corrupt. In that case, working out what's actually wrong is probably more trouble than it's worth. You can just create a new project and add the items in this one to it as existing items. For a small project, you're looking at a few minutes effort at most.

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425

Comment: *"You can just create a new project and add the items in this one to it as existing items"*. If you go down this route, having the two projects in the same solution means that you can simply drag forms and other items between projects in the Solution Explorer. If they are in different solutions, you can right click the target project and select Add -> Existing Item and then navigate to the item in the source project folder.

Comment: Already I tried to insert the form from the project and it works correctly
Unfortunately, it gave me more errors than I could solve
As I told you, I am a beginner
Thank you for all your response and trying with me
Thank you very much

Comment: Whether the error is specific to a particular form, and if so, try to provide information about that form.