# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not save; currently locked by another user

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I am barely new to VB.NET and as part of our final project, we are tasked to create a program and use MS Access as our database. Now the problem is whenever we are 'Updating' the picture in our database, the error will always show **System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException (0x80004005): Could not save; currently locked by another user.** And the funny thing is that when we repeatedly click the Update Button it will now prompt **Account updated** and proceeds to update the picture in the database. How can I fix this?

Our code is as follow:

```
 Using modify As New OleDbCommand("Update AccountDetails Set [Picture] = @Picture WHERE ID = " & id_modify & "", connect)
    connect.Close()
    connect.Open()

    Dim arrImage() As Byte
    Dim mstream As New System.IO.MemoryStream()
    picNewAccnt.Image.Save(mstream, Imaging.ImageFormat.Png) 'the picture box that will show the picture inserted
    arrImage = mstream.GetBuffer

    Dim filesize As UInt32
    filesize = mstream.Length
    mstream.Close()
    mstream.Dispose()

    Try
        modify.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Picture", arrImage)
        modify.ExecuteNonQuery() 'the part where the error always occur
        MsgBox("Account updated ", MsgBoxStyle.Information, "Account Update Successful")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.ToString)
    End Try

End Using
```

I tried checking all connections to the database and making sure that it is enclosed in the Using Statement.

Comment: Where are the Using statements you mentioned? -- You should not store the Connection object(s), declare and dispose any of these where they're used. Reusing Connection objects can also slow down read operations quite a lot, especially with an Access database -- This is quite wrong: `arrImage = mstream.GetBuffer()`, see the docs to understand why

Comment: There's some code in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425) that may be helpful.