# windows c# syntax error in insert statement

Tags: c#

i am trying to add data to my ms access database I watch almost all yt tutorials but its still gives me an error on run time

```
 private void btn_add_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                OleDbCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into Employee(Employee ID, Firstname, Lastname, Email, Username, Password)values('" + txt_employee_id.Text + "','" + txt_employee_firstname.Text + "','"
                + txt_employee_lastname.Text + "','" + txt_employee_email.Text + "','" + txt_employee_username.Text + "','" + txt_employee_password.Text + "')";
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                MessageBox.Show("Record Save", "Access Connected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Access Connected", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                conn.Close();
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: use a prepared statement. don't use string concat or your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69638011/10024425

Comment: Your code is open to [SQL injection attacks](https://bobby-tables.com/). You should use parameterized queries instead.
Also: NEVER store passwords in plain in a database. Use salted hashes instead.

Comment: If the given advices didn't help you might tell us what error you get just saying "still gives me an error on run time" isn't that helpful we need the actual error to work with and help you.

Comment: It apparently gives "an error". Usually such an error (exception) gives some details about the issue. Please add those to your post, but first use parameters - that  possibly solves the error already

Answer (score 1):

Column names with spaces need to be enclosed in square brackets. Employee ID

```
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Employee([Employee ID], Firstname, Lastname, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txt_employee_id.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", txt_employee_firstname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", txt_employee_lastname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", txt_employee_email.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", txt_employee_username.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txt_employee_password.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

And then use parameterized queries instead of concatenating strings to avoid SQL injection attacks.

The `?` is a placeholder for parameter values. The parameter value will be passed in at runtime.

And the `@p1`, `@p2`, `@p3`, `@p4`, `@p5`, and `@p6` are the parameter names, which are associated with their corresponding parameter values using the AddWithValue() method.

This is a common way of preparing SQL statements to avoid SQL injection attacks. You can read more about the [SQL Parameters Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0)

Comment: Do not use AddWithValue: [1](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/), [2](http://chrisrickard.blogspot.com/2007/06/addwithvalue-is-evil.html), [3](https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/).

Comment: [cmd.Parameters.Add\(String parameterName, Object value\) is deprecated now. Instead use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue\(String parameterName, Object value\)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29554589/724039)

Comment: @Luuk: `Add` is not deprecated - read the comments and the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.add?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlParameterCollection_Add_System_String_System_Object_). However, I think that _broccoli_ is deprecated.

Comment: [brocolli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xSMYy.png) ?  And I am not sure what's wrong with the [documentation of AddWithValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparametercollection.addwithvalue?view=dotnet-plat-ext-7.0), it seems like no warning there that it should not be used.

Comment: I'm still having the same error

Comment: @XDponce but you still haven't told us *what* that error is